# URL Rewrite , url change on postback event

Tags: c#, asp-classic, vbscript

I am currently working on classic asp application and we have URL rewrite pages.

In those pages, we have small form which I have to validate. When I press the submit button it validates the page but change the URL of the page.

I want to stop changing URL.

I had same issue with ASP.NET C# so I used `Form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;`

How can I do same with classic asp application?

Comment: Just change the action of the form to point on the same page, can't see where you're stuck sorry..

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of `Request.RawUrl` is

```
dim myUrl
myUrl = Request.ServerVariables("URL")
```

So

```
<Form action=<%=myUrl%> 'and the rest of the details
```

However, the `Request.ServerVariables("URL")` doesn't include the `querystring` (if present).

If you need that, then you'll have to build it manually, do something like

```
dim myUrl
myUrl = Request.ServerVariables("URL") & "?" & Request.QueryString
```

(you may want to put in an if else statement to make this cleaner).